# MKMapView overlays get reset on appDidBecomeActive

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mapkit

I have this map view with a bunch of overlays. When I hit the home button and re-open it, all the overlays disappear for a second and immediately re-appear. At first I thought it was my code that was doing it but I put breakpoints pretty much everywhere and none of my code seems to be triggering the "reset". Even `mapView:viewForOverlay:` doesn't get called before the overlays reappear.

I thought maybe this is an inevitable behavior of `MKMapView`, but it seems like Maps.app doesn't do it either — if you calculate a route and quit/re-open the app, the overlays stay there the whole time.

I'm thinking maybe MKMapView clears all of its annotations/overlays by default on quit so it takes less memory while staying backgrounded. Is there any way to avoid this? Kinda like Maps.app does?

EDIT: [here's a small project](http://cl.ly/ExGw) I put together to demonstrate the problem. Just launch it in Simulator, click the home button, and re-open it. You'll see the map path overlay disappear for a moment.

Comment: are you using arc? arc will release the objects as soon they aren't used, so when going background, they'll disappear, and as soon they are used, they'll reappear. that's just a thought, since I've had views that are resetting on background switch.

Comment: I am using ARC, but my controller holds a `strong` reference on the mapView, which itself should be holding a `strong` reference on its overlays no?

Comment: My MapKit app does the same thing, I think that's just the way it is. Why is this a problem?

Comment: @shawkinaw there's no reason for the overlays to flicker on app relaunch. Imagine if tableViews would have their content flicker on app relaunch; it would have been widely reported and probably been fixed quickly. Map overlays are just less common so the bug went unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a follow-up than an actual answer, but basically this issue has been flagged as a bug by Apple. I submitted this as a TSI to Apple a while ago and received the following answer:

> Thanks for providing a sample project. I don't see any issues in your
>   code. At this point I recommend escalating the issue to engineering by
>   filing a bug about the "flicker" from the MKPolylineView being redrawn
>   at https://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/ and sending me the bug
>   number so I can use it to follow up.

I then submitted radar #11041378

> Thanks again for your bug report. As it happens, I don't have a
>   workaround for you at this time. Engineering is still working on the
>   issue, but I don't have a timeline for a fix.
>
> I'll go ahead and leave this incident open for you as long as bug
>   11041378 is open. If you have any questions about it's status in the future, or the status of a workaround, feel free to reply back and I
>   will check it for you.
>
> If you have any comments for engineering, or want to tell the story of
>   why it's important to your situation, I'd actually encourage you to
>   put that directly in the bug. Since it's been assigned to engineering,
>   any comments will go directly to them.

I appended the following comment that describes why the issue is important to me:

> This bug feels rather important to me as the user expects to find the
>   app in the exact state he left it when he quit the app. The flickering
>   overlays (sometimes disappearing for less than second, other times for
>   2-3s) may get the user confused about what is going on, when all he
>   really wants is to interact with the map/overlays right away.

Haven't heard back from Apple since. Hopefully this will get fixed in iOS 6?